# Data fetching successfull whereas show processlist is empty

Tags: mysql, go

Making `SQL Query` through `go` using `database/sql` is working as expected but the `show processlist` is showing an empty list for the specific `Requested Host`.

Comment: if the query is exceptionally quick it won't appear in processlist quick enough. You could add 'SELECT SLEEP(60) as sleepval, ... {rest of query' to ensure its there.

Comment: @danblack Awesome. Got it. Was searching for private IP instead of public IP as Host.